# Retrieve Subject Alt Name from x509 in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, smartcard, x509, pki

I am trying to retrieve the SAN from a DoD Smart Card and running into an issue where the subject alternative name is returning `othername:<unsupported>`.  I haven't found many examples of parsing this but I would have assumed X509 li in node would parse it. Looking for any direction on best way to get the email address.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const cert = req.socket.getPeerCertificate();
  app.set("user", cert);

  const x509 = new X509Certificate(cert.raw);
  console.log(x509.toJSON());

  next();
});
```

Tried a library from F5 that they used for nginx but wasn't able to find the correct properties to pass for it to parse the email address.

https://clouddocs.f5.com/training/community/nginx/html/class3/module1/module17.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **node-forge** library to parse the Subject alternative name extension - othername attribute.

For the below config,

```
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = bp.client.com
otherName.1 = 2.16.123.1.2.1.2.1.2;UTF8:somevalue
```

The following code will parse the certificate and print the value of the othername attribute.

```
var forge = require('node-forge');
var asn1 = forge.asn1;
var certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem('-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n' + req.socket.getPeerCertificate(true).raw.toString('base64') + '\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----');
var otherNames = certificate.extensions.filter(ext => ext.id == '2.5.29.17').find(ext => ext.altNames).altNames.filter(altNames => altNames.type == 0);
var othernameValueforOid = ""
for(entry of otherNames) {
    if(entry.type === 0){
        if(entry.value[0].type === 6 && asn1.derToOid(entry.value[0].value) === '2.16.123.1.2.1.2.1.2'){
            othernameValueforOid = entry.value[1].value[0].value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(othernameValueforOid)
```

where 2.5.29.17 is the oid of subject alternative name attribute.
You can modify the code according to your requirement. Hope this helps!